# How to Call WSDL Webservices from iPhone Application?

Tags: ios4

I am making an iPhone app using `WSDL` Web-Services, but I have no idea how to call it from iPhone.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at wsdl2objc: http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/

There are a couple other tools that help create a SOAP interop layer for iOS apps, but I would suggest only using them if you have to. Take a look at using JSON to communicate with your web service.

Comment: I already have webservices with  .wsdl extension , so i have to implement it. is there  any basic toutorial link with Wsdl web services.

Comment: The tool I mentioned will create service classes allowing you to interact with existing Web services. Take a look at their wiki for a tutorial on how to use the tool: http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are some tools that would generate code for you. I don't like using them as customizing,debugging it would be painful. So here is what I do:
Download SOAP UI ( google search it ) and then give it your wsdl and endpoint it will generate sample request for you. You can get response as well. 
In your XCode project View controller ( usually I do this in my Model separated from View Controller) Construct your POST using NSURLConnection Asynchronous connection,then in your didFinishLoading you have gotten the data. If response is XML then parse the XML using NSXML or libxml parser.

This will get you started.